# 六道 is it rikudou or rokudou

Tags: readings

I'm not sure whether to read 六道 *rikudou* or *rokudou*.

Comment: It can be read both ways unless otherwise specified. For example, it seems always _rikudou_ in Naruto.

Answer (score 1):

According to Wikipedia, it can be read either way.

https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%85%AD%E9%81%93

「ロク」 is the Wu-reading（呉音） and「リク」, the Han-reading （漢音）.